# Get Actual Country from IP

Tags: php, ios, web-services

I'm developing an iOS application and I want to know my actual country (like: US-ES-EN-etc) or in my application (without using location) or on the web side (php) through http request.

It's possible?

Comment: You can use http://ip-api.com/docs/ I used it some time ago and got good results

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we will be using the ip geolocation api:

```
<?php
    $ip = "8.8.8.8";
    $curl = curl_init("http://ip-api.com/json/$ip");
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE]);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));

    echo $response->country;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is however its not that accurate if your visitor will use one non-typocal proxy for example... anyway to make that as accurate as possible you can try to guess the real IP like this:

```
<?php
    if( array_key_exists( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER ) $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    elseif( array_key_exists( 'REMOTE_ADDR', $_SERVER ) $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    elseif( array_key_exists( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', $_SERVER ) $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else die( "can't guess ip" );
?>
```

then you can use third party service to get the country code for example:

http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=83.24.10.141

http://ip-api.com/json/83.24.10.141

etc.

Comment: the only variable I can take is REMOTE_ADDR but the ip I get from my device is always based on sim card... I have a spanish sim and I'm in Italy and I get only Spain from my ip with https://ipinfo.io/6x.xx.xx.xx/json ....